# play framework in an sbt subproject - no applicaton loader defined

Tags: playframework, sbt, guice

I am trying to create a play framework project as an sbt subproject.

As minimal configuration I created this build.sbt:

```scala
name := """api-skeleton"""
organization := "my.domain"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).aggregate(api)
lazy val api = (project in file("api")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

libraryDependencies += guice
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "5.0.0" % Test

scalaVersion := "2.13.1"
```

Running `sbt project api run` play framework starts as expected, informs me that it is listening to port 9000 and waits for requests. Sending a request to it will result in this error message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: No application loader is configured. Please configure an application loader either using the play.application.loader configuration property, or by depending on a module that configures one. You can add the Guice support module by adding "libraryDependencies += guice" to your build.sbt.
     scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:30)
     play.api.ApplicationLoader$.play$api$ApplicationLoader$$loaderNotFound(ApplicationLoader.scala:51)
     play.api.ApplicationLoader$.apply(ApplicationLoader.scala:159)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1.$anonfun$reload$3(DevServerStart.scala:188)
     play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1.reload(DevServerStart.scala:181)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1.get(DevServerStart.scala:141)
     play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.handleRequest(AkkaHttpServer.scala:296)
     play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.$anonfun$createServerBinding$1(AkkaHttpServer.scala:186)
     akka.stream.impl.fusing.MapAsync$$anon$30.onPush(Ops.scala:1261)
     akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processPush(GraphInterpreter.scala:541)
     akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.execute(GraphInterpreter.scala:423)
     akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.runBatch(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:624)
     akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell$AsyncInput.execute(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:501)
     akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:599)
     akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.akka$stream$impl$fusing$ActorGraphInterpreter$$processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:768)
     akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:783)
     akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:533)
     akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:531)
     akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.aroundReceive(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:690)
     akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:573)
     akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:543)
     akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:269)
     akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:230)
     akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:242)
     java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
     java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
     java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
     java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

Googling this message (and reading it) tells me that I need to add guice to my project. Which I did as it is visible in the build.sbt. Also something about deleting the target folders in a similar StackQuestion, which I have attempted as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I ran into was caused by the libraryDependencies not being used for all projects as I assumed. So guice was never loaded and the error message was quite precise.

In order to load guice for the sub project I created a dependency file in my projects directory called `Dependencies.scala`. It looks like this:

```scala
import sbt._
import play.sbt.PlayImport._

object Dependencies {
  val play: Seq[ModuleID] = Seq(
    guice
  )
}
```

I can now provide my sub project with the dependencies by doing this in my `build.sbt`:

```
lazy val api = project
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala)
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= Dependencies.play
  )
```

And now it works.